# Unable to execute Jenkins job using powershell

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I am trying to run a Jenkins job using the powershell command which is not working.

The error I am seeing is

**Valid crumb was not provided**

Following are the powershell commands I ran:

```
$crumb = Get-JenkinsCrumb -credentials $creds -uri "https://mywebpage.com"

Invoke-jenkinsjob -credentials $creds -crumb $crumb -uri "https://mywebpage.com" -Name "MyJob"
```

Can someone please suggest to fix this issue. Iam providing the crumb value in the command but seems like it is not fixing the issue

Comment: Where did those commands come from? They don't come with PowerShell (and in all my time using Jenkins I've never heard the term "crumb" used, though I'm far from an expert).

Comment: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Jenkins/1.2.1

Comment: It's possible someone here will know but you might also want to engage with the project: https://github.com/PlagueHO/jenkins